# possition() mod в XSLT - сортировка элементов

Tags: сортировка, xslt, position

есть задача вывести элементы в шахматном порядке.

[image: что надо]

чет-нечет не совсем корректно работает в таком виде

```
<xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="position() mod 1 != 0 and position() mod 4 != 0">
            <div class="pego-columns pego-columns3 fl single-service-image">
                <xsl:if test="image_small != ''">
                    <img alt="{name}" src="{dir}{image_small}" class="attachment-full size-full" />
                </xsl:if>
            </div>
            <div class="pego-columns pego-columns3 fl single-service">
            <h1 class="service-title"><xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select=" substring-before(name,' ')"/><span><xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select=" substring-after(name,' ')"/></span></h1>
                <p class="service-excerpt"><xsl:value-of select="description" disable-output-escaping="yes" /></p>
            </div>

        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise> 
            <div class="pego-columns pego-columns3 fl single-service">
            <h1 class="service-title"><xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select=" substring-before(name,' ')"/><span><xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select=" substring-after(name,' ')"/></span></h1>
                <p class="service-excerpt"><xsl:value-of select="description" disable-output-escaping="yes" /></p>
            </div>
            <div class="pego-columns pego-columns3 fl single-service-image">
                <xsl:if test="image_small != ''">
                    <img alt="{name}" src="{dir}{image_small}" class="attachment-full size-full" />
                </xsl:if>
            </div>

        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
```

[image: Вот то, что получается]
отрабатывает только первые 4 элемента, дальше все сползает. Подскажите как изменить position mod, что надо добавить что бы он корректно отрабатывал? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Остаток при делении любого числа на 1 будет 0. Вам нужно смотреть на остаток при делении на два

```
<xsl:when test="position() mod 2 = 1>
  <div class="pego-columns pego-columns3 fl single-service-image">
  ...............
```